# UI-Router how to determine current state in resolve entries as either parent or child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

States are set up to allow for re-use by injecting parent resolve entries into children, which all works except for the creation of a new package instance.  I can't figure out how to determine that the dashboard.package state is the actual state that is be transitioned to.  Even if the second parameter meant for the child state is present only one appears in $state.params so I can't check for isUndefined and know that dashboard.package is the state.

Logic for the states are if no second parameter is present no document exists and new instance needs to be created, otherwise state is edit and instance exists.

```
// Parent dashboard
.state('dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/dashboard.html',
    resolve: {
        UserAuth: ...,
        GetPackageTypes: ...
    }
}

  // Parent dashboard package
  .state('dashboard.package', {
      url: "/package/:packageInstance",
      templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/views/package.html',
      controller: 'PackageController',
      controllerAs: 'packageCtrl',
      resolve: {
          GetPackageType: [function(){

              // HTTP request for package type 
          }],
          CreatePackage: ['$state', '$stateParams', 'GetPackageType', 
                function($state, $stateParams, GetPackageType){

              // ISSUE: Determine if dashboard.package is the actual state???
              // if it is then create new package instance, otherwise will drop 
              // into dashboard.package.edit and package instance will be used

              // Example URL for this state: #/dashboard/package/type

              // Even if both params exist only see one here so no good
              console.log("state.params = ", $state.params);

              // Shows previous state name so no good
              console.log("state.current = ", $state.current);
              console.log("state.current.name = ", $state.current.name);
              console.log("state.$current.self.name = ", $state.$current.self.name);

              // Returns false so no good
              console.log("$state.is = ", $state.is('dashboard.package') );
              console.log("$state includes = ", $state.includes('dashboard.package') );
          }]
      }
  }

    // Child dashboard package
    .state('dashboard.package.edit', {
        url: "/edit/:packageInstanceId",
        templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/views/package.html',
        controller: 'PackageController',
        controllerAs: 'packageCtrl',
        resolve: {
            GetPackageInstance: ['$state', '$stateParams', 'GetPackageType', 
                function($state, $stateParams, GetPackageType){

                // HTTP request for package instance uses package type

                // Example URL for this state: #/dashboard/package/type/edit/3858
            }],
        }
    }
```

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

To avoid any more wasted time trying to figure this out, or putting together some funky work around, which will potentially fail in some future update I ended up creating a second abstract state dashboard.package with all my controller, templateUrl, and initial resolve with a single parameter for the package type, and splitting create package out into separate state dashboard.package.create at same level as dashboard.package.edit.  Works great with no headache if any finds it useful.

```
// Parent dashboard
.state('dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/dashboard.html',
    resolve: {
        UserAuth: ...,
        GetPackageTypes: ...
    }
}

.state('dashboard.package', {
            url: "/package/:packageType",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/views/package.html',
            controller: 'PackageController',
            controllerAs: 'packageCtrl',
            resolve: { 
                GetPackage: // injecting parent GetPackageTypes and using parameter
            }
}

.state('dashboard.package.create', {
    url: "",
    resolve: { 
        CreatePackage: // injecting parent GetPackage
    }
}

.state('dashboard.package.edit', {
    url: "/edit/:packageinstance",
    resolve: { 
        GetPackageInstance: // injecting parent GetPackage and using parameter
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//$state.current.name will have either name of parent or child.
resolve: {
  isChild: function($state, STATES) {
    return $state.current.name === STATES.CHILD_NAME;
  }
}
```